# Can we develop a custom UITababar?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Is this possible for us to customize the UITabbar as it is in the attached image for an iPAd App?

My App is only meant for Landscape orientation..

Will apple allow this?

[image]

I know that this same can be done using a UIToolbar and having tab like buttons. Since the number of tabs I will have in my app is around 5, I can not think of implementing them in a single view using UIToolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that even if this kind customization is done, Apple will  not approve the App.

I have actually used UIView to place different UIButtons in them and produce similar effects as that of UITabbar.